# How to deal with Property Constraints?

Tags: javafx

How can I add some constraints to multiple Properties? Assuming we have the following Properties:

```
    DoubleProperty min =  new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "max", 0.0);
    DoubleProperty max =  new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "min", 1.0);
    DoubleProperty value =  new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "value", 0.0);
```

and the constraint is

```
    min.get() <= value.get() && value.get() <= max.
```

Maybe it is easier to achieve this for custom `Control`s, because the values can only be set in the FX Application thread and therefore can't be set concurrently?

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2014/05/13/how-to-ensure-consistency-of-your-observable-state.html) about using the ReactFX framework to do things like this.

Comment: Thanks @James_D! I also found a [tutorial](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX/wiki/InhiBeans#solution) for implementing a boolean and gate with InhiBeans. In this tutorial both Properties are set via a single method `setInputs`. So the properties can be blocked until all is done. But in the case of custom control (a slider for example with min, max and value), these properties can set out of such a method. It isn't usual to make these properties read only, becouse it would prevent from using the nice binding functionality. Have you a solution for it?